# How can I merge cells with html, css and php?

Tags: php, html, css

I'd like to merge cells with identical values in the columns:

```
<td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$endereco->quadra}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$endereco->lote}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$requerimento->interesse_regularizacao ? $requerimento->interesse_regularizacao : 'Nenhum'}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$instrumento_titulacao ? $instrumento_titulacao->tipo_instrumento_titulacao_nome : 'Nenhum'}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$endereco_lote}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$endereco->tipo_endereco}}</td>
```

I want to leave the form this way:

[image: table1]

But today is printing this way:

[image: table2]

My code:

```
 @foreach($requerimentos as $requerimento)
        @if($requerimento->situacao == 'Finalizado')
            @php 
                $lote = $requerimento->lote()->first();
                $endereco = $lote->endereco()->first();
                if($endereco){
                    $endereco_lote = $endereco->tipo_logradouro. ' '. $endereco->logradouro. ', nº '. $endereco->numero. ' - '. $endereco->bairro. ', '. $endereco->cidade. ' - '. $endereco->estado. ', '. $endereco->cep; 
                }else{
                    $endereco_lote = '';
                }                                    

                $instrumento_titulacao = \App\Models\TipoInstrumentoTitulacao::find($requerimento->instrumento_titulacao_id);

                $requerentes = $requerimento->todosRequerentesFormatadoRequerimento();
            @endphp
            @foreach($requerentes as $requerente)
               
                
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$endereco->quadra}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$endereco->lote}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$requerimento->interesse_regularizacao ? $requerimento->interesse_regularizacao : 'Nenhum'}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$instrumento_titulacao ? $instrumento_titulacao->tipo_instrumento_titulacao_nome : 'Nenhum'}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$endereco_lote}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$endereco->tipo_endereco}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$requerente->requerente_nome}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$estado_civil ? $estado_civil->estado_civil_descricao : ''}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$regime_casamento}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$documento}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$rg}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$filiacao}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$nome_conjuge}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$cpf_conjuge}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px;">{{$rg_conjuge}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
        @endforeach
```

Someone can help me?

I took this example of data:

```
$datas = [
    ["QUADRA", "LOTE", "CLASSIFICAÇÃO INDIVIDUAL", "DIREITO REAL OUTORGADO", "TIPO LOGRADOURO", "LOGRADOURO", "NÚMERO", "COMPLEMENTO", "BAIRRO", "CIDADE", "ESTADO", "CEP", "TIPO DE USO", "NOME"],
    [7, 2, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Maria Luiza Vargas Siqueira"],
    [7, 2, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Reginaldo Montilla Nobrega"],
    [7, 2, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Marilena Coutinho Vasconcellos"],
    [7, 2, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Rinaldo Barros Monnerat"],
    [7, 2, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Luzineide Salomão Bezerra"],
    [6, 10, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "Saco", "Quadra A1", 767, "Apartamento", "Portal da Alegria", "Mata Verde", "MT", "77006-412", "Vago", "Wescley Vilar Mourão"],
    [8, 9, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação Fundiária", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Rebeca Rodrigues Camacho"],
    [8, 9, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação Fundiária", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Everton de Arruda Kuster"],
    [8, 9, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação Fundiária", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Casemiro Anastacio Germano Bernardes"],
    [8, 9, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação Fundiária", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Theo Araujo Albenaz Rangel"]
];
```

and this example of code:

```
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($datas[0] as $footer) {
    echo '<th>' . $footer . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

$lines = count($datas);
for ($i = 1; $i < $lines; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($datas[$i]); $j++) {
        $value = $datas[$i][$j];
        if ($i > 0 && $datas[$i - 1][$j] === $value && $j < 6) {
            continue;
        }
        $rowspan = 1;
        for ($k = $i + 1; $k < $lines; $k++) {
            if ($datas[$k][$j] === $value && $j < 6) {
                $rowspan++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($rowspan > 1) {
            echo '<td rowspan="' . $rowspan . '">' . $value . '</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

However the results appear this way:
[image: example]

It is almost there, but i want simultaneously.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#colspan

Comment: Great question! I can think about how to go about it the hard way, but surely, there must be an existing library somewhere to accomplish this. In your situation, is it always vertical (column-based) duplication, or are there cases when it's horizontal (duplicate rows)? Off hand rows would be much easier to do.

Comment: Hey man,it's always in duplicate rows, the problem that need to check 6 columns in the row with the before row

Comment: `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes. Very basic HTML knowledge. You could also go with grid templates and flexbox instead of tables.

Comment: sure @MarkusZeller, however it's not so simple to implement, because the loop foreach, and I need check if repeat 6 columns in the row

Comment: Just a use a counter and a `$prev` variable. If it is the same as before increment the counter, on new row reset. So you know how many colspans you have.

Comment: Do two loops. One to mark duplicate adjacent cells and one to generate the HTML.

Comment: @Quentin can you give me a example?

Comment: Psuedo code. Might need some finessing. COUNT = 1; WHILE previousCell.value == currentCell.value; COUNT++; previousCell = currentCell; DONE; currentCell.rowSpan = COUNT; (Keeping in mind that currentCell is now the first cell in the group with identical values thanks to the loop).

Comment: @Quentin I tried to do a new code, however it is almost there! My problem is verify the first 6 values simultaneously. I edited my answer, can you check there?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example how you can count and do the spans at least for the cols.

```
$rows = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $values = [];
    $prev = null;
    $repeat = 0;
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        if ($value === $prev) {
            $repeat++;
            continue;
        }
        if ($prev !== null) {
            $values[] = [$prev, $repeat];
        }
        $repeat = 1;
        $prev = $value;
    }
    $values[] = [$value, $repeat];
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        [$content, $repeat] = $value;
        if (1 === $repeat) {
            echo "<td>$content</td>";
            continue;
        }
        echo "<td colspan=$repeat>$content</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=3>1</td><td colspan=3>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td colspan=4>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
```

## Part 2 - detecting identical rows

```
$datas = [
    ["QUADRA", "LOTE", "CLASSIFICAÇÃO INDIVIDUAL", "DIREITO REAL OUTORGADO", "TIPO LOGRADOURO", "LOGRADOURO", "NÚMERO", "COMPLEMENTO", "BAIRRO", "CIDADE", "ESTADO", "CEP", "TIPO DE USO", "NOME"],
    [7, 2, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Maria Luiza Vargas Siqueira"],
    [7, 2, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Reginaldo Montilla Nobrega"],
    [7, 2, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Marilena Coutinho Vasconcellos"],
    [7, 2, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Rinaldo Barros Monnerat"],
    [7, 2, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Luzineide Salomão Bezerra"],
    [6, 10, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação de Posse", "Saco", "Quadra A1", 767, "Apartamento", "Portal da Alegria", "Mata Verde", "MT", "77006-412", "Vago", "Wescley Vilar Mourão"],
    [8, 9, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação Fundiária", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Rebeca Rodrigues Camacho"],
    [8, 9, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação Fundiária", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Everton de Arruda Kuster"],
    [8, 9, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação Fundiária", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Casemiro Anastacio Germano Bernardes"],
    [8, 9, "Reurb-E", "Legitimação Fundiária", "3ª Travessa da Rua", "Lindolfo Mascarenhas", 876, "Casa", "São Judas Tadeu", "Mata Verde", "ES", "29200-620", "Misto", "Theo Araujo Albenaz Rangel"]
];

for ($index = 0, $count = count($datas); $index < $count; ++$index) {
    $sameRowCount = countSameRows($index, $datas);
    echo "row $index has the next $sameRowCount rows with the first 6 columns in common\n";
}

function countSameRows(int $index, array $data): int
{
    $sameCount = 0;
    for ($count = count($data) - 1; $index < $count; ++$index) {
        if (array_slice($data[$index], 0, 6) !== array_slice($data[$index + 1], 0, 6)) {
            return $sameCount;
        }
        $sameCount++;
    }

    return $sameCount;
}
```

```
row 0 has the next 0 rows with the first 6 columns in common
row 1 has the next 4 rows with the first 6 columns in common
row 2 has the next 3 rows with the first 6 columns in common
row 3 has the next 2 rows with the first 6 columns in common
row 4 has the next 1 rows with the first 6 columns in common
row 5 has the next 0 rows with the first 6 columns in common
row 6 has the next 0 rows with the first 6 columns in common
row 7 has the next 3 rows with the first 6 columns in common
row 8 has the next 2 rows with the first 6 columns in common
row 9 has the next 1 rows with the first 6 columns in common
row 10 has the next 0 rows with the first 6 columns in common
```

Comment: I tried to do a new code, however it is almost there! My problem is verify the first 6 values simultaneously. I edited my answer, can you check there?

Comment: New code, new question, please! Please revert the question to the original, because it was answered already.

Comment: See my answer updated how to detect identical "future" rows.